# How to use an 'if' code only when the first activity's name is equal to a string?

Tags: android, if-statement, android-intent, intentfilter

I have this if code in my activity:

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle.getBoolean("fourthSection")){
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.stats);
        new uq().execute();

        otherLayout = true;
    }
```

How can I get the name of the activity that sends the intent, and to apply the code above only when the first activity's name is equal to "Profile"?

Comment: you could put in the bundle the Activity's name

Comment: No. I want that only if Profile.java activity sends the intent, it will check the if code.

Comment: subclass the receiving activity, and start it only from profile

Answer (score 0):

- Single Caller: For Example: You just want to call from your `Profile` class then add an `boolean` which indicates that it's from `Profile` class.
- Multiple Caller: For Example: There are multiple callers then add an `int` for identifying from which calls it's been called.

**Implementation**

1. In `Profile` class

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, SOME_ACITIVITY.class)
   intent.putExtra(ANY_KEY, true); // Set it true for Profile class
   startActivity(intent);
   ```
2. Another or Destination class

   Write the below code in `onCreate()` method

   ```
   if (getIntent() != null) {
        boolean callFromProfile = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(ANY_KEY, false);
        if (callFromProfile) {
                // Write your logic here as we are called from Profile Activity
        }
   }
   ```

Comment: @IdoNaveh Can you post little more code from both the `Activity` ?